# bootstrap: google map modal isn't working property when outside div class="container-fluid" is set "height: auto"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Recently I'm working on some webpages([Like this link](http://dpw-tw.byethost7.com/events/shonenomnyoji_teatime/), and never mind it's all Chinese and some Japanese contents).

When I set "height: auto" for outside div which is set class="container-fluid"(exclude navbar)

e.g.:

HTML:

```
<div id="information" class="container-fluid">
    <!-- following content omitted -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#information {
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: auto;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #FFE7DE;
    background-image: url("shonen_5.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover; */
}

#information .well {
    background: rgba(255, 231, 238, 0.75);
}
```

Google Map modal is not working property.

Is any solutions to fix this issue?

Comment: Note: [CSS](http://dpw-tw.byethost7.com/events/shonenomnyoji_teatime/css.css) and [JavaScript](http://dpw-tw.byethost7.com/events/shonenomnyoji_teatime/js.js) for this webpage

Comment: Google maps require a fixed predefinied height, otherwise or don't show the maps or show only a small part

Comment: You need to post a complete, working example of your code (HTML/CSS/jS) in a Snippet. [mcve]

Comment: @vanburen  I'm sorry I forgot to attach some snippets. I'll edited this ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fidex px height or % fidex height. the important things is a (pre)definied height like this way:

```
#information {
   padding-top: 50px;
   height: 90%;
   color: #000;
   background-color: #FFE7DE;
   background-image: url("shonen_5.jpg");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-size: cover; */
}
```

Comment: It works! And also I've rewrite modal for Google Map to make sure it work property. Your suggestion is appreciated.